# how to set long list of properties and values in matlab

Tags: matlab

MATLAB question:

Let's say I have a very long list of property names in a cell array.

> properties = {'property01', 'property02', 'property03', .... , 'property50'};

and the corresponding values for each property.

> values = [val01, val02, val03, ...., val50];

Now I have a function which takes variable number of properties as input depending upon certain condition. One of the main restriction to correctly use the function is to call it only once with all the required properties fed in as inputs. (So I cannot call function in a for loop, looping for different property setting each time)

e.g. If some condition forces me to use 4 properties, then correct usage would be:

> output = someFunction(data, 'property01', val01, 'property02', val02, 'property03', val03, 'property04', val04);

How can I provide variable number of properties to the function which is to be called only once?

Mayur Narsude

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pv = [properties;values];
output = someFunction(data, pv{:});
```

Basically, you create a 2xN cell aray, and when it gets linearized the properties and values alternate.

(That's on the calling side.  Inside the function definition, you would use varargin as proposed in another answer.  I guess it wasn't clear which you were asking about in your question.)

Comment: Thanks @nhowe for the trick. 

pv in my case is contains char strings in the first row and in the second row it has cell containing a very large matrix that I want to pass. In short: properties = string and value = cell 

So when I pass this to the function as you suggested, it obviously does not convert cell2mat before passing and then function call becomes nonsense since it expects a matrix as value. I do not have access to the function where I can modify it after passing it to the function. Any further ideas? 

Cheers,Mayur

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your comment.  Can you give a specific example of the types of arguments involved?

Comment: > pv = [properties;values]; 
> properties = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3', ..., 'propN'];
> values = [val1, val2, val3, ..., valN];
> whos val1
> cell double
So basically val1 upto valN each are cells containing matrices of say 1x2000 values. That means,
>  output = someFunction(data, pv{:});
generates an error. All the properties are passed as character strings, which is correct. But all the values are passed as cells where as function expects matrices for values. So I need a mechanism to convert values in cell before I pass it to the function. Obviously using cell2mat on pv is not the solution.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have val1 etc. in cells.  But I think you could do something like this in that case:  pv = [properties;cellfun(@(a)a{1},values,'UniformOutput',false)];

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `varargin`. Using that as one of the input variables in your function definition will allow you to call the function with different numbers of inputs.